# RealityKit project in Xcode is not fullscreen

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, xcode12, realitykit

in Xcode 12.4, create new RealityKit project
run in on simulator ( iPhone 12 Pro for example)

it is not full screen

I tried many thing but won't work

you can replace :

```
   var body: some View {
        return ARViewContainer()
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
```

with

```
var body: some View {
    Text("Test")
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.red)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}
```

same issue

i suspect some parameter in info.plist file

[image]

could you help on this please, thanks

Comment: It is full screen for me, are you presenting `ContentView` inside a `NavigationView`?

Comment: no, just the default project

Comment: thanks for feedback, I think I will uninstall Xcode and reinstall it

Comment: Before you do that can you attach a screenshot? Something like this shouldn't need a reinstall

Comment: done, but its exactly the template that did that to me, no change. same thing when run on real device. those big black parts in top and bottom stays black on device, in Xcode Preview its good, all full screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution is from [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/665031):

in project setting:
General -> App Icons and Launch Images
Set property (that is empty) "Launch Screen File" to LaunchScreen.Storyboard